# Вставка в unordered_map/set

Tags: c++

Если количество корзин в `unordered map/set` равно количеству элементов для вставки, гарантировано ли константное время вставки каждого элемента в худшем случае?

Comment: Это как это оно может быть гарантировано? Все зависит от вашей функции хеширования.

Comment: @user238463: Неправильно понял вопрос, ответ удалил.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, конечно, не гарантировано. Напишите "плохую" функцию хеширования (например, всегда возвращающую одно и то же значение) - и запросто получите линейное время вставки, ибо все вставляемые элементы пойдут в одну корзину.

Идеальное линейное время вставки вы получите только в том случае, если внешняя функция хеширования (вкупе с преобразованиями хэш-значения внутри `unordered_map`) каким то чудом образовали [*идеальную функцию хэширования*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). Но на это рассчитывать в общем случае не приходится.